# How do I get qt creator to give me the exit code of my program?

Tags: qt, ide

No matter what I do, qtcreator always gives back:

```
/home/tim/build-foo-Desktop-Debug/foo exited with code 0
```

for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Am I just looking in the wrong place for the exit code, or does qt creator not support this?

Comment: Is this a better fit for superuser? I figured since it is a development question, I should put it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Qt Creator running your code in a terminal? If yes, go to Projects, Run and then uncheck "Run in terminal". That works for me.

Comment: It pops up a terminal window that says press "return to close", I will double check though.

Comment: Yes, that means it is running the app in a terminal. Do what I said and it should work. At least for me it worked on Linux.

Comment: Okay, that did it, but ideally I would like to have the terminal output as well. I assume it uses some sort of shell script to run in a terminal. any idea where it is?

Comment: Terminal output is shown in Qt Creator window. Both stderr and stdout. As to why the return code is wrong when run in the actual terminal I don't know. You can refer to Qt Creator sources.

Comment: Okay... thanks... It'll do for now. I'll look into it later when I have more time. You solved my immediate problem in any case. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it turns out this is a known bug in the version I have. It has been allegedly fixed in the master branch. This is a good workaround though in any case.